# Is a ring homomorphism determined by where it sends idempotents?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Given two rings $R,S$, and a ring homomorphism $f : R \to S$, is the homomorphism uniquely determined by where the idempotents of ring $R$ are sent by $f$?

I was thinking about how linear transformations are determined by where basis vectors are sent, and so it seemed natural to extend this idea to Rings by the claim that Ring homomorphisms are determined by where the generators of the ring are sent, but since rings have two binary operations it didn't seem like a very useful extension.

But idempotents in ring $R$ are always sent to idempotents in ring $S$ by ring homomorphisms, so I thought maybe I could classify homomorphisms in this way instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. For example, $R$ may have no idempotents besides $1_R$ which has to be sent to $1_S$ (my ring homomorphisms are unital and yours should be too), which tells you nothing about where anything else in $R$ will go. This happens with, for instance, fields or polynomial rings. So this fails very badly.

> it seemed natural to extend this idea to Rings by the claim that Ring homomorphisms are determined by where the generators of the ring are sent, but since rings have two binary operations it didn't seem like a very useful extension.

This is a useful idea. For example, any homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}[x]\to R$ is determined by where $x$ is sent to, and if $K/F$ is a splitting field for $p(T)\in F[T]$ then any $F$-automorphism of $K$ is determined by how it permtues the zeros of $p$ (which generate $K/F$).

Comment: AFAIK $0$ is also idempotent.